# How to create a like system in strapi

Tags: strapi

I would like to create a like system.
I have got list of restaurant and that registerd users can like it.
So retrieve who liked it, and if (i'm logged in) i can see that i already like that restaurant.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a many to many relation between your User and Restaurant models. And to add a like you will have to update your restaurant or user by adding your Restaurant ID or you User ID as new relation.

Here is the documentation https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/models.html#many-to-many